# Inicializar e alterar variável estática de uma maneira thead safe. Este código faz sentido? O Intellij IDEA acha que não

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Olá!

Estou buscando uma maneira segura de inicializar **e alterar** uma variável estática que será compartilhada por diferentes threads que estarão acessando o seu valor.

A ideia é que, em algum momento, vou verificar que esta variável precisa ser alterada e quero que a sua alteração seja thread safe, sem afetar as threads que estão acessando o seu valor atual.

O ideal era não fazer com que as treads parem para esperar a atualização, pois o valor atual ainda é válido.

Estou usando a variável em um `Component` (`@Service`) do Spring, para poder chamar os serviços.

O código abaixo mostra a solução atual. Basicamente, é uma classe para que outras classes sempre peguem o token atualizado, fazendo a primeira autenticação caso o token esteja nulo ou fazendo a renovação do token caso ele esteja perto de expirar.

Código atual (não testado ainda):

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class TokenService {

    private static TokenData TOKEN = null;

    private final LoginService loginService;
    private final RefreshTokenService refreshTokenService;

    public String getToken() {

        if (TOKEN == null) {
            synchronized (TOKEN) {
                // preciso verificar novamente se está nulo, pois pode ter ocorrido de uma outra thread ter inicializado já o Token
                if (TOKEN == null) {
                    TOKEN = autenticar();
                }
            }
        }
        return obterToken();
    }

    private TokenData autenticar() {
        AutenticacaoResponse autenticacaoResponse = loginService.autenticar();
        return new TokenData(autenticacaoResponse.getAuthToken(), autenticacaoResponse.getIssuedAt());
    }

    private String obterToken() {
        if (isPertoExpirar()) {
            synchronized (TOKEN) {
                // preciso verificar novamente se está perto de expirar, pois pode ter ocorrido de uma outra thread ter já alterado o Token. 
                // Aqui eu até poderia abrir mão deste controle, pois não teria problema se duas ou mais threads chamassem o refresh.
                if (isPertoExpirar()) {
                    AutenticacaoResponse autenticacaoResponse = refreshTokenService.atualizar(TOKEN.getToken());
                    TOKEN = new TokenData(autenticacaoResponse.getAuthToken(), autenticacaoResponse.getIssuedAt());
                }
            }
        }
        return TOKEN.getToken();
    }

    private boolean isPertoExpirar() {
        return TOKEN.isFaltaMeiaHoraExpirar();
    }
}
```

Minha ideia foi colocar um `syncronized` na variável `TOKEN`, mas o Intellij IDEA **alerta para dois problemas** ao tentar fazer isto:

```
Dereference of 'TOKEN' may produce java.lang.NullPointerException
Synchronization of a non-final field 'TOKEN'
```

Eu poderia tentar inicializar a classe `TokenData` e saber se há um token válido dentro dela, mas ainda assim estaria recebendo o segundo alerta. Não vejo muito problema nisto, mas de acordo com o Intellij IDEA:

> Reports synchronized statements where the lock expression is a reference to a non-final field. Such statements are unlikely to have useful semantics, as different threads may be locking on different objects even when operating on the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sincronize sobre o token. Sincronize sobre um objeto final.

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();

synchronized (lock) {
    ...
}
```